# When should we use CATransformLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I have read the documentation and several examples, but still cannot understand when exactly to use a `CATransformLayer`. A normal `CALayer` flattens everything at the `z = 0` plane, but isn't that what a `CATransformLayer` does too? A mathematical explanation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 14):

To fully understand what are the differences between CALayer and CATransformLayer, you should read this [article](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/introduction-to-3d-drawing-in-core-animation-part-1/)

It is the best tutorial which explains how to use `CATransformLayer`.

But to say briefly,
Consider a scene(`CAlayer instance`) where we create 4 planes at the same X, Y coordinates but with different Z and add it as `subLayers` to scene.And rotate the scene by some angle.

So, we might expect it looks like,
[image]

But instead it looks like,
[image]

This is due to the fact that a CALayer is incapable of managing the depth of a 3D hierarchy and it just flattens the scene to a single Z level. To correct that depth issue, we use `CATransformLayer`, it has depth understanding and renders based on it.

**Note**:images are taken from the article.

Comment: please accept the answer if you think is explains your question.

Answer (score 5):

A CATransformLayer is used to transform its sublayers in 3D, and does NOT flatten them down.

> Unlike normal layers, transform layers do not project (i.e. flatten) their sublayers into the plane at Z=0.

It’s something you’d use if you want to do a transform on a group of layers together but you didn’t want to do to each one individually because you wanted the flexibility of changing the transform in one place...kind of like a camera / world / model transform in OpenGL.

That said, I’ve never had occasion to use one, because I’ve never tried to do true 3D in LayerKit. I assume one was used for that stacking demo at WWDC a few years ago, there might be example code for that.

If I found myself starting to use a CATransformLayer nowadays, I’d switch to SceneKit, but that’s not on iOS yet.