# CALayer flattening sublayers

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

I am creating a UI where we have a deck of cards that you can swipe off the screen.

What I had hoped to be able to do was create a subclass of UIView which would represent each card and then to modify the transform property to move them back (z-axis) and a little up (y-axis) to get the look of a deck of cards.

Reading up on it I found I needed to use a CATransformLayer instead of the normal CALayer in order for the z-axis to not get flattened.  I prototyped this by creating a CATransformLayer which I added to the CardDeckView's layer, and then all my cards are added to that CATransformLayer.  The code looks a little bit like this:

In init:

```
// Initialize the CATransformSublayer
_rootTransformLayer = [self constructRootTransformLayer];
[self.layer addSublayer:_rootTransformLayer];
```

constructRootTransformLayer (the angle method is redundant, was going to angle the deck but later decided not to):

```
    CATransformLayer* transformLayer = [CATransformLayer layer];
transformLayer.frame = self.bounds;

// Angle the transform layer so we an see all of the cards
CATransform3D rootRotateTransform =  [self transformWithZRotation:0.0];
transformLayer.transform = rootRotateTransform;
return transformLayer;
```

Then the code to add the cards looks like:

```
// Set up a CardView as a wrapper for the contentView
RVCardView* cardView = [[RVCardView alloc] initWithContentView:contentView];

cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
if (cardView != nil) {
    [_cardArray addObject:cardView];
    //[self addSubview:cardView];
    [_rootTransformLayer addSublayer:cardView.layer];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Note that what I originally wanted was to simply add the RVCardView directly as a subview - I want to preserve touch events which adding just the layer doesn't do.  Unfortunately what ends up happening is the following:

[image: Flattened Cards]

If I add the cards to the rootTransformLayer I end up with the right look which is:

[image]

Note that I tried using the layerClass on the root view (CardDeckView) which looks like this:

```
+ (Class) layerClass
{
    return [CATransformLayer class];
}
```

I've confirmed that the root layer type is now CATransformLayer but I still get the flattened look.  What else do I need to do in order to prevent the flattening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use views, you see a flat scene because there is no perspective set in place. To make a comparison with 3D graphics, like OpenGL, in order to render a scene you must set the camera matrix, the one that transforms the 3D world into a 2D image.
This is the same: sublayers content are transformed using `CATransform3D` in 3D space but then, when the parent `CALayer` displays them, by default it projects them on *x* and *y* ignoring the *z* coordinate.

See [Adding Perspective to Your Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH8-SW13) on Apple documentation. This is the code you are missing:

```
CATransform3D perspective = CATransform3DIdentity;
perspective.m34 = -1.0 / eyePosition; // ...on the z axis

myParentDeckView.layer.sublayerTransform = perspective;
```

Note that for this, you don't need to use `CATransformLayer`, a simple `CALayer` would suffice:

[image: CALayer can handle 3D projections]

here is the transformation applied to the subviews in the picture (`eyePosition = -0.1`):

```
// (from ViewController-viewDidLoad)
for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
    CGFloat dz = (float)(arc4random() % self.view.subviews.count);
    CATransform3D t = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.f, 0.f, dz),
                                          0.02,
                                          1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    v.layer.transform = t;
}
```

The reason for using `CATransformLayer` is pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671551/when-should-we-use-catransformlayer). `CALayer` "rasterizes" its transformed sublayers and then applies its own transformation, while `CATransformLayer` preserves the full hierarchy and draws each sublayer independently; it is useful only if you have more than one level of *3D-transformed* sublayers. In your case, the scene tree has only one level: the deck view (which itself has the identity matrix as transformation) and the card views, the children (which are instead moved in the 3D space). So `CATransformLayer` is superfluous in this case.

Comment: Will double check my code and verify this helps.  Excellent answer though, really helpful!

Comment: @Pietro : Thanks for answer. But what to do if I want frame of views in Perspective mode? I am getting wrong frame into this mode.

Comment: @girish_pro what do you mean with "frame of views"? I'm not familiar with this layout concept. Perhaps you want to alter the [`frame` property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center) of the layer?

Comment: @PietroSaccardi Can you please review my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264038/how-to-make-center-calayer-after-resizing-superview

Comment: If I get the "contents" property of CATransformLayer, will I get a CGImageRef that is a composite of all its sublayers?

Comment: @JamesBush according to [Apple’s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410773-contents) you should get `nil`. I think it would be inefficient to pre-compose and store every layer into a `CGImageRef`.

Comment: The answer to my question is definitely no; I tried kg put right after I asked. Had it worked, though, it wouldn't be inefficient at all, at least not for the reason you stated. There is no pre-composed state to a CGImage; it is the image data itself. Creating a UIImage or CIImage from it is the only “composing”, if you will, and those are simply wrappers for the image data—as cheap and easy as it gets; they don't copy the data. Any expensive processing associated with a CGImage is long over once you have it; beyond that, everything else has a negligible impact.

Comment: @JamesBush Good point, but I'm not 100% sure that every layer has a backing storage (what would be the meaning of [this property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410905-shouldrasterize?language=objc)?). I could not find conclusive information though.